# Error: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: main.m

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a very simple code in python, basically I try to create indexes for each table in my database (already exists). The database and my script file are located at the same folder. After fetching a list of names of the tables and trying to create indexes for the first table, I get this error message:

> `c.execute("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "+tableName[m]+"Date ON
>   "+tableName[m]+" (date)")`; sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table:
>   main.m

The database doesn't have any table with this name (main.m)!

my code:

```
import sqlite3
DBname = 'myDatabase.sqlite';
# connect to the database
conn = sqlite3.connect(DBname);
c    = conn.cursor();
c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'");
tables = c.fetchall();
print("\nCreating the indices for each table in the database ...");
for m in range (0,len(tables)):
    tableName = tables[m][0];
    print(tableName)
    c.execute("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "+tableName[m]+"Date ON "+tableName[m]+" (date)");
    c.execute("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "+tableName[m]+"Year ON "+tableName[m]+" (year)");
conn.close()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: MySQL has nothing to do with SQLite, these are different products.

Comment: Should `tableName[m]` just be `tableName`?

Comment: You print out the tableName variable. Does it show the correct table name?

Comment: @Shadow : Thanks for editing my post. Yes it shows the correct name of the first table!

Comment: In this case why do you use `tableName[m]` form when you create the sql statement? Use simply `tableName`.

Comment: @TimothyG. the database contains many tables (more than 56,000 tables)

Comment: It's in a loop though.  `tablename` should change with each iteration.

Comment: @Shadow I forget to take out [m] when I posted. I can't edit my post now, could you please take them out of the code. Thanks

Comment: 56k tables??? I hope that was a joke or you mixed up number of records with number of tables

Comment: Are you saying that your code does not contain `tableName[m]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `tableName` variable shows the correct table names as per your comment, then just use `tableName` when you create the sql statement instead of `tableName[m]`:

```
c.execute("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "+tableName+"Date ON "+tableName+" (date)");
c.execute("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "+tableName+"Year ON "+tableName+" (year)");
```