# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: main.source

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I am making an API that uses Python Flask and Sqlite3.  Most of it works. Specifically:

- all GET endpoints/SELECT queries work
- two POST endpoints/INSERT INTO queries work

However, the remaining POSTs/INSERT INTOs do not work.  They all have the same sqlite3.OperationalError with the message:

```
no such table: main.source
```

This is weird because none of the queries use a table called "source" or "main.source". I print the queries before I `execute` them, and I have tried copy/pasting the queries into the sqlite3 command prompt.  The queries have no issues when I do that.

The other weird thing is that all the INSERT INTO queries call the same function to create the actual query (which in turn calls the function to run queries ... used by ALL queries most of which work).  Only some of the INSERT INTOs cause this error.

Some potentially useful information:

An excerpt from createdb.sql

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  buyer INTEGER NOT NULL,
  seller INTEGER NOT NULL,
  amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
  currency VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  fee INTEGER NOT NULL,
  source INTEGER NOT NULL,
  description TEXT NOT NULL,
  status VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The insert into that Python prints/that throws an error in `execute`:

```
INSERT INTO transactions (status, fee, description, source, seller, currency, amount, buyer) VALUES ('initiated', '1', 'nada', '1', '2', 'USD', '1000', '1');
```

And some stuff from Sqlite's prompt:

```
sqlite> .tables
conversations  sources        users        
messages       transactions   withdrawals
sqlite> SELECT id, description FROM transactions;
1|hella mulah
2|payback
3|woohoo
sqlite> INSERT INTO transactions (status, fee, description, source, seller, currency, amount, buyer) VALUES ('initiated', '1', 'nada', '1', '2', 'USD', '1000', '1');
sqlite> 
sqlite> SELECT id, description FROM transactions;
1|hella mulah
2|payback
3|woohoo
4|nada
```

For references, here is a POST command that has no error despite using most of the same stuff:

```
INSERT INTO users (session, balance, name, firebaseToken) VALUES ('ABCDEFG', '0', 'Mr Miyagi', 'ABCDEFG');
```

**There are a lot of similar questions on SO but here's why they are not duplicates:**

- [flask/sqlalchemy - OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311199/flask-sqlalchemy-operationalerror-sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-table) Yes, I created the tables before using them.
- [Why am I suddenly getting "OperationalError: no such table"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262771/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-operationalerror-no-such-table) my Flask app is able to find the database no problem (and most of the queries work without a hitch).  To be safe I made my DB in `connect` an absolute path.  No effect.
- [Error: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: main.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743428/error-sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-table-main-m) I don't do any weird indexing + if I did this the copy pasting wouldn't work
- [Python Sqlite3 - Data is not saved permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691504/python-sqlite3-data-is-not-saved-permanently): I do call commit in `@app.teardown_appcontext`. I also tried calling commit after every query.  No effect.

**Other stuff I considered but ruled out:**

- There is a list of disallowed names, but these are not included http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html.  `transactions` is close to `transaction` but not the same.  `source` is not on the list.

I'm sure this will end up being some kind of silly messup but any ideas on where to look would be much appreciated.  I also tried Googling this error but I didn't see anything helpful.

--- more code ---

This is database.py

```
import sqlite3
import flask

import backend

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    output = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        output[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return output


def get_db():
    if not hasattr(flask.g, 'sqlite_db'):
        flask.g.sqlite_db = sqlite3.connect("/my/absolute/path/var/data.db"
        )
        flask.g.sqlite_db.row_factory = dict_factory
        flask.g.sqlite_db.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;")
    return flask.g.sqlite_db


def query(query, args=(), islast=False):
    print(query) # this is where the print from before is
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rowvector = cur.fetchall()
    if islast:
        cur.close()
    return rowvector


@backend.app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    if hasattr(flask.g, 'sqlite_db'):
        flask.g.sqlite_db.commit()
        flask.g.sqlite_db.close()
```

This is selected sections from apiimpl.py

```
QUERY_INSERT = "INSERT INTO"
QUERY_SELECT = "SELECT"
QUERY_UPDATE = "UPDATE"

def queryhelper(*args, **kwargs):
    sqltxt = None
    selectstr = None
    if kwargs["action"] == QUERY_INSERT:
        sqltxt = "{} {} ({}) VALUES ({});".format(
            QUERY_INSERT,
            kwargs["table"],
            ", ".join(["{}".format(x) for x in kwargs["cols"]]),
            ", ".join(["'{}'".format(x) for x in kwargs["vals"]]),
        )
        # pretty sure this next bit is not relevant but here it is anyway
        selectstr = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE ROWID=(SELECT last_insert_rowid());".format(
            kwargs["table"],
        )
    elif kwargs["action"] == QUERY_SELECT:
        # not relevant
    elif kwargs["action"] == QUERY_UPDATE:
        # not relevant
    else:
        assert(kwargs["action"] in [QUERY_INSERT, QUERY_SELECT, QUERY_UPDATE,])
    try:
        rv = db.query(sqltxt) # this is where the error is thrown
        if selectstr:
            return db.query(selectstr)
        else:
            return rv
    except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
        # this is where the error is caught
        return api_error("SQL error (1): {}", str(e), code=500)

def append(tablename, args):
    tabledata = TABLES().tablenamemap[tablename]
    print("tablename: " + tablename) # "tablename: transactions"
    # a bunch of error detection 
    rv = queryhelper(
        action=QUERY_INSERT,
        table=tablename,
        cols=args.keys(),
        vals=args.values(),
    )
    # not shown: potentially returning json.dumps(rv)
    return rv


def transactions_post(req):
    # a lot of stuff to turn req into validargs
    # printed validargs: {'status': 'initiated', u'fee': u'1', u'description': u'nada', u'source': u'1', u'seller': u'2', u'currency': u'USD', u'amount': u'1000', u'buyer': u'1'}
    return append("transactions", validargs)


@backend.app.route("/transactions", methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT"])
def transactions_route():
    return {
        "GET":  transactions_get,       # get list of transactions
        "POST": transactions_post,      # initiate a transaction
        "PUT":  transactions_put,       # change transaction status
    }[flask.request.method](flask.request)
```

P.S. the purpose of this question is not to discuss the implementation, but if you want to leave a comment that's ok with me.

--- in response to comment --

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" AND name="transactions";
table|transactions|transactions|4|CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  buyer INTEGER NOT NULL,
  seller INTEGER NOT NULL,
  amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
  currency VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  fee INTEGER NOT NULL,
  source INTEGER NOT NULL,
  description TEXT NOT NULL,
  status VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY (buyer) REFERENCES users(id), -- do not want to delete on CASCADE
  FOREIGN KEY (seller) REFERENCES users(id), -- do not want to delete on CASCADE
  FOREIGN KEY (source) REFERENCES source(id) -- do not want to delete on CASCADE
)
```

Comment: What do you get if you run this query 'SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" AND name="transactions";'. Are you using sqlalchemy or just using the sqlite3 database adapter directly?

Comment: @bigjake edited the question to include the response.  Also, I thought someone asked for more code so I added it in.  I am using sqlite3 directly

Comment: if kwargs["action"] == QUERY_INSERT:  this translates to if kwargs["action"] == "INSERT INTO"  or am I missing something?

Comment: @LAS yeah I think that's right.  You can tell bc when I print the query it starts with INSERT INTO

Comment: the error message itself doesn't make any sense as your queries don't mention a source table in the main schema.  Try your_db_instance_here.set_trace_callback(print).  This will echo everything executed by the database. See if there are any unexpected queries going through. If that fails you could try searching for a sqlite3 logging handler like [this](https://gist.github.com/giumas/994e48d3c1cff45fbe93)

Comment: Something that also might be worth mentioning is that if you don't commit for each query, your error handler might just print the last query that went through instead of the one that caused the error when you do commit. You could temporarily set it up so that every statement gets executed individually. I might be off base here, its hard to tell by looking at your code

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash  Where in the def query does it fail?  After the execute or after the fetchall?  Because when you do an insert you're not fetching anything.  I would think the cur.close would commit or rollback depending on it's definition but I wonder what happens if isLast isn't fired?

Comment: @bigjake I added `set_trace_callback` and that seems to print every query.  I don't see any more info.  I also added a commit after "fetchall" which also didn't change anything :/

Comment: @LAS it fails after execute.  isLast should always be false.  Pretty sure it would just close/reopen the db connection if i accidentally set isLast to true.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash Should this primary key "  FOREIGN KEY (source) REFERENCES source(id) -- do not want to delete on CASCADE" reference source(id) or sources?

Comment: @bigjake HOLY CRAP thank you so much.  That fixed it.  I feel really dumb now.  If you want to make an answer I'll mark it correct.  Thank you x 1000.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash no prob, happens to all of us. glad we could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are referencing a table that doesn't exist based on your .tables command.

```
sqlite> .tables
conversations  sources        users        
messages       transactions   withdrawals
```

And this create table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  buyer INTEGER NOT NULL,
  seller INTEGER NOT NULL,
  amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
  currency VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  fee INTEGER NOT NULL,
  source INTEGER NOT NULL,
  description TEXT NOT NULL,
  status VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY (buyer) REFERENCES users(id), -- do not want to delete on CASCADE
  FOREIGN KEY (seller) REFERENCES users(id), -- do not want to delete on CASCADE
  FOREIGN KEY (source) REFERENCES source(id) -- do not want to delete on CASCADE
                               -- ^ there is no source table
)
```

If you change **source(id)** to **sources(id)** you should be good.

Comment: The real lesson here is to set foreign keys on before running the create script.  I should have gotten an error in the CREARE TABLE

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash It's easier to remember that when your using a full blown RDBMS like Mysql, Postgres and some fancy graphical toolkit like PHPMyAdmin etc. It can slip your mind when your using sqlite and you have to remember to manually call `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` _every_ time you open the database.